# flickering when updating ellipse after fillrect in c++ win32

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

All the action happens in c++ win32 application.
currently used rect fill method (redrawing quite often so it flickers):

```
RECT r;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
RECT mRect;
brush_real = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));

{


    dc = GetDC(GetDlgItem(hwnd, 1));
    GetClientRect(GetDlgItem(hwnd, 1), &mRect);
    FillRect(dc, &mRect, brush_real);

    HBRUSH circleBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(Roriginal, Goriginal, Boriginal)), oldBrush;
    oldBrush = (HBRUSH)SelectObject(dc, circleBrush);

    Ellipse(dc, mRect.left, mRect.top, mRect.right, mRect.bottom);

    SelectObject(dc, oldBrush);

    ReleaseDC(GetDlgItem(hwnd, 1), dc);

    DeleteObject(oldBrush);
    DeleteObject(circleBrush);
}
DeleteObject(brush_real);
```

this doesn't works fully as intended, because ellipse draw flickers when drawed after fillrect(which fills black background), i didn't yet figured out how to fill background once and for good on object initialization in dialog.
What could you offer ?

Comment: Use double buffering. For a quick intro see the first half of [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/01/03/508694.aspx).

Comment: yes but i could avoid the need of double buffering if i would have background set up once.